# Where I can buy iOS tabbar icons one by one?

Tags: ios, icons, uitabbar, application-icon

Hey! I am looking to buy some iOS icons for my apps tabbar, I want them to be retina display icons. I am looking for a place where I can buy icons one by one, as I rather not want to buy a pack as I don't need 90% of them... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you already seen http://www.thenounproject.com/ ?